# Javascript new Date() changed in firefox?

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, iceweasel

So I was wondering if the `javascript` function `Date()` recently changed for Firefox or even other browsers.

At first I would get a date output like this: `Mon Apr 13 2015 22:18:08 GMT+0200 (West-Europa (zomertijd))`

But now it's outputting something like this: `2015-04-13T20:15:18.322Z`

I had a script that was depending on the first format so it broke while nothing changed in my code. That's why I started investigating and found this as the problem.

I was wondering what's up with this. (I'm not asking for a formatting solution, just wondering why it's formatted like this)

**Update 1**: figured it might be useful to add version numbers of the browsers I tested (all with the same result).

- Firefox developers edition: 39.0a2 (2015-04-07)
- Iceweasel 31.4.0
- Firefox 37.0.1

**Update 2**: Code example:

```
new Date();
-- output -- Date 2015-04-13T20:57:39.622Z
```

Turns out this is an `UTC` or `Zulu time` format. So now the question is: Why is it outputting a UTC date while it didn't do that before.

Comment: The language spec at least hasn't changed in this regard. Though, the exact format that's used isn't specified. It's just a "[*String representing the current time (UTC)*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.2)."

Comment: Regional settings for the computer(s) tested with perhaps?

Comment: @JamesWilkins I tested it on 2 different PC's and on my VPS. Same result. I don't think the regional settings has anything to do with it.

Comment: Are you just converting `Date()` directly to a string?  What's the code?

Comment: Just simply `new Date();` thrown in the browser's console. @JamesWilkins

Comment: @BramDriesen The console will have its own behavior for how it displays an object. This isn't guaranteed to be consistent between browsers. Try specifying how it's converted to a string -- `new Date().toString()`, `new Date().toISOString()`, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yes .toString() does indeed the trick. But why did it change all the sudden? I have some javascript code that broke because the default format changed.

Comment: I agree, I just tried .toString() and it works fine.

Comment: @BramDriesen The default format is mostly left up to the implementation to determine, so it's open to revisions at any time. If you need the result to be consistent, use a method that provides a specific format -- e.g. `toISOString()`.

Comment: Why not then provide a code sample so people can test it out?

Comment: @JamesWilkins Yes I know that works. But I didn't ask for a solution to this since I already knew that `.toString()` was working. It's just why did it change all the sudden.

Comment: I think you miss my point.  Unless your code is running in a special debugging console, it should work properly.  If you run `var s = ''+Date();` in Firefox you get the result expected.  Nothing has changed, thus, it must be something related to your code.

Comment: Only a developer working on Firefox or those other products by Mozilla can answer your question, but I expect that it has to do with the addition of [`toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) to the Date prototype. That outputs the same value as what you are seeing in your console.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I think that's the source of this weird format indeed. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Date()` returns a date object. The console in Firefox helps you as a developer to debug things, and Mozilla may have changed the representation of an object in the console. Maybe they first just showed the date the object represented, and now they show a representation of the object that you can explore (there's a triangle ▶ that you can click on which expands the representation and shows more properties of the object).

It shouldn't matter for the behavior of your programs. When you output a date on a page, you would not directly print the object, but convert it to a string for example, which you get in the case of `new Date().toString()`. This behavior won't likely just change for no reason.

Comment: I guess I'm going to select this as the answer since it's makes sense. Still weird it changed all the sudden.

Comment: It not weird it changed all of a sudden. Firefox's developer tools are updated regularly to improve the workflow for developers. The change won't break any existing programs, since programs don't run inside the developer tools. The developer tools are really just to help the developers debug their programs, and if they improve these tools, it might look different, but that doesn't mean your code is doing something different.

Comment: It actually did brake something for me since I have to run the script on the client side and it was relying on the first date format. But yeah a simple tostring did the trick ;)

Comment: I think you might mistake the developer console change with a different bug you have. If you show the source code that broke maybe I could tell you what happened.

Comment: The thing is, nothing changed in my code. It was working last week, when I tried this week it didn't work and no one changed stuff in the code. So it will probably an update with the dev console. It's all sorted now ;)

Comment: I know these situations, you think nothing has changed and it doesn't work anymore so something else must have changed. But blaming the developer tools doesn't make sense, unless your program is really depending on the developer tools, which also doesn't really make sense (unless you're making a plugin for the developer tools or something).

Comment: In this case it's a script for a site that has to be deployed through the console. So it does make sense. There is no other way for me to run the script on the site. (no it's nothing malicious, it's a chat bot for a music site)

Comment: Ok, the output of date objects changed in your program, but it's behavior shouldn't have been changed. You shouldn't rely on the developer console as a consistent environment to make programs. But if you need to use it, you can always be pretty sure that strings will just get outputted as strings, so converting an object to a string would be a good practice in that case.